# NodeJs: Getting MyDocuments Path on Windows

Tags: windows, node.js

How can I retrieve the MyDocuments path with NodeJS.

So I would like to get something in NodeJs with the following C# code:

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
```

Thx & Regards
Stefan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

```
var Q = require('Q');

var getUserDoc = function(callback) {

    var Winreg = require('winreg');
    var deferred = Q.defer();

    var regKey = new Winreg({
        hive: Winreg.HKCU,
        key: '\\Software\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Explorer\\User Shell Folders' 
    });

    var myDocFolder = regKey.values(function(err, items) {
        for (var i in items) {
            if (items[i].name === 'Personal') { 
                deferred.resolve(items[i].value);
            }
        }
    });
    deferred.promise.nodeify(callback);
    return deferred.promise;


}

getUserDoc().then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: That's not a good way to look up the information. Better call the official API than hacking the registry

Comment: I do not like it, too, but is there another possiblity?

Comment: Don't know what you can do from node.js. Just that Win32 offers APIs to get these locations.

Comment: Agree with David, you have to use Node fs.

Comment: The value of this reg key would not be updated if the user changed the Documents folder location manually. This is very common when the user's Documents folder takes up too much disk space.

Answer (score -2):

You should use the environment variable instead :

```
function getUserDoc() {
  return process.env.USERPROFILE+'\\Documents';
}
```

This assumes that you run Win7 or above. For Win XP, it'd be `\\My Documents`. You can easily check for one or the other in your function.

<s>Also, you can use the package [path-extra](https://github.com/jprichardson/node-path-extra) which offers the shortcut homedir()</s>

In this case you'd have to do :

```
var path = require('path-extra');

function getUserDoc() {
  return path.homedir()+'\\Documents';
}
```

Both of these solutions allow you to not give your app the credentials for checking the registry. 
And run way faster than the promise + registry hack you've found.

**Update**: `path-extra` do not supports homedir any more. https://github.com/jprichardson/node-path-extra/commit/ce7a0b67ce07ca06ca2eeabf62621e1327b1d113 
+1 for ingenuity though, I've saved that snippet for possible use ;-)

Comment: Patah path.homedir() and process.env.USERPROFILE do not point to the correct directory if the user has changed the path tot he MyDcouments folder in Windows ...
Therefore both variant do unfortunately not work ...

Comment: Note that Windows XP translates the documents folder. So in french, it'll be `\\Mes Documents`. Vista and newer work (don't know how: aliases? different display name?)

Comment: Downvoted because you can move each folder independantly. Case in point: my co-worker has moved his downloads folders to `D:\Downloads` so it doesn't work.